# What Twig variable can i use to view Page Title or Taxonomy Name for a Taxonomy Type page

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms, 8

In Drupal 8 I need a way to get the Current pages title or Taxonomy name/ID.

In the template taxonomy-term.html.twig the variable works:

```
{{ term.id }}
```

I need the variable to work in page.html.twig

the following variables work only if the current page type is a node and not a taxonomy:

`{{ head_title_array.title }}` and `{{node.field.category.entity.tid.value}}`

I need to access this variable in the page template in order to use it as a class for a region based on what taxonomy page type is being displayed.

**EDIT:**

prints out page__taxonomy__term__# or null if not a taxonomy page:

```
{{ theme_hook_suggestions }}
```

prints out the title of the current page regardless of type:

```
{{ page['#title'] }}
```

Comment: See this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192232/get-current-taxonomy-in-template-preprocess-html how to get the term id in preprocess

Comment: thanks but i'm not sure where this goes. i installed Devel and i have been using knit to try and make twig variables more readable.however if i use a view to display taxonomy type pages than some variables do not work